# Retrieve all values in a column that are not present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, I used to be able to take a dataframe column, compare it against a second dataframe column, and get all the items missing from that second column like so:

```
notYetIncluded = notYetIncluded.loc[~notYetIncluded["ID"].isin(df_o["ID"])]
```

However, that no longer works in the updated pandas (I get the error `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'`). How do I do that?

The part that seems to cause the breakage is this: `notYetIncluded["ID"].isin(df_o["ID"])`

I don't know if it helps, but these columns currently store just numbers like `4150`, `5808`, etc. They're all 4 digits or less long.

For example:

notYetIncluded:

`0     5747
1     5746
2     5725
3     5722
4     5720
5     5707
Name: ID, dtype: object`

df_o:
`24    5365
4     5720
15    5599
Name: ID, dtype: int64`

Comment: what are the datatypes of these columns?

Comment: This one in particular is a number

Comment: are they both 'numbers'? try `print(dataframe.dtypes)` and let us know what the datatypes of these columns are

Comment: Just try updating; `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: I'm already running the most recent pandas: '0.20.1'.
This script has been around for a year or so, so is there something I need to change about this line or the data storage to make it work with the pandas changes? It says the datatype of notYetIncluded is 'object' and 'df_o' is int64, yet they're both created using data from the same dataframe, and in fact no changes are made to the "ID" column at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.astype(str)` to cast your columns to string and then compare.

```
n = notYetIncluded
notYetIncluded = n[~n["ID"].astype(str).isin(df_o["ID"].astype(str))]
```

Comment: It seems to be this part that causes the breakage `notYetIncluded["ID"].isin(df_o["ID"])`

Comment: @Elliptica How about showing us some data, perhaps.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I've added some data to my problem statement. Your solution here works well as a temporary measure, though I would still like to understand what has changed such that my data used to be able to be compared and no longer can't be, since neither my code nor the data I'm using has changed.

Comment: @Elliptica I'm sorry. There's nothing I can say looking from the data you've posted. My system rightly parses it as int64 as it should be. If there's anything else happening from your side, it's possibly due to errors in your CSV, or maybe as you load it.